# Is Hausdorff Measure equal to Hausdorff Content on rectifiable (metric) spaces?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Let $(X,d)$ be an $\mathcal{H}^n$-rectifiable metric space, i.e. there exits a collection of Lipschitz maps from measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $X$ such that $ \mathcal{H}^n(X \backslash \cup_i f_i(A_i)) = 0 $.

Is it true that for any subset $A \subset X$,
$$ \mathcal{H^n}(A) = \mathcal{H}^n_\infty (A) \ .$$

The claim is true on $X = \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that the same equality fails horribly if we consider $\mathcal{H}^k$ for $k<n$ -- think of an infinitely long curve inside a bounded set.

If this helps: I am interested in small scales, so, you might consider asymptotic behavior as $\text{diam} (A) \to 0$.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: What if X is a circle in the plane with the metric inherited from the plane?  To handle the asymptotic version consider a union of countably many circles with shrinking radii.

Comment: What do you mean when you write $\mathcal{H}^n_{\infty}$?

Comment: Amir, for the definition of Hausdorff content see e.g.  http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/all2.pdf

Comment: Thanks @YuvalPeres I in fact like your answer better because the problem is not just at a single point in your example, unlike the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no. For example, $X$ may be a countably infinite collection of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $X$ is $1$-rectifiable.

For any ball $B$ centered at the origin, $B\cap X$ has finite Hausdorff $1$-content but infinite Hausdorff $1$-measure.

If you have some kind of Ahlfors regularity of the measure, then you can get comparability of Hausdorff measure and Hausdorff content.

Comment: Thank you lots!